# How to make a sprite that follow a circular path while its size changes?

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit, scale

I already made that the ball follows a circular path, but the only problem is that I want that when touches began the path grow and the ball keep following the path. I have tried adding an `SKAction` but the ball doesn't follows the path. Hope someone can help me.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var circuloPrincipal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circulo")
var circuloFondo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloFondo")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

  circuloPrincipal.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
  circuloPrincipal.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2 - 105)

  circuloPrincipal.color =  UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.9, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
  circuloPrincipal.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
  circuloPrincipal.zPosition = 3.0

  circuloFondo.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
  circuloFondo.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
  self.addChild(circuloFondo)
  circuloFondo.color = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.9, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
  circuloFondo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
  circuloFondo.zPosition = 1.0

  circuloPrincipal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(frame) , (CGRectGetMidY(frame) + circuloFondo.size.width/2) )
  addChild(circuloPrincipal)
  let dx = circuloPrincipal.position.x - frame.width / 2
  let dy = circuloPrincipal.position.y - frame.height / 2

  let radius = (circuloFondo.frame.size.width / 2) - 20.0

  let radian = atan2(dy, dx)
  let playerPath = UIBezierPath(
     arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)),
     radius: radius,
     startAngle: radian,
     endAngle: radian + CGFloat(M_PI * 4.0),
     clockwise: true)

  let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
  circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  circuloFondo.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5))
}
```

//New code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    //fondoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("fondoEfecto"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if (circuloFondo.actionForKey("scaleTo") == nil) {
        let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5)
        circuloFondo.runAction(scale,withKey:"scaleTo",optionalCompletion: {
 //here the error occours         


   // scaleTo is terminated
            // stop followTrackPath
            self.circuloPrincipal.removeActionForKey("followTrackForever")
            // re-run in the new path
            let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
            self.circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow),withKey: "followTrackForever")
        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You must add my extension to have also the "completion" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could make some corrections that can help you for the rest of the project.

This below works well with Swift 2.x, don't try it with Swift 3.x:

First of all I want to introduce this extension that can be useful :

```
extension SKNode
{
    func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )
    {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock( completion )
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            runAction( compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            runAction( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }

    func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
        if self.actionForKey(key) != nil {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
self.runAction(myAction,withKey: "myActionName",optionalCompletion: {
    // do whatever you want when action is finished..
})

if self.actionForKeyIsRunning("myActionName") {
   // this action is up
}
```

**Where to place this extension:**

You can place this extension also after the last brace of your class, like this example:

```
class MyClass: SKScene {
   ...
}  // end of MyClass

extension SKNode
{
   ...
}
```

---

This line could become:

```
    circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow),withKey: "followTrackForever"))
```

and the `scaleTo` lines could be:

```
    if !circuloFondo.actionForKeyIsRunning("scaleTo") {
            let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5)
            circuloFondo.runAction(scale,withKey:"scaleTo",optionalCompletion: {
               // scaleTo is terminated
               // stop followTrackPath
               self.circuloPrincipal.removeActionForKey("followTrackForever")
               // re-run in the new path 
               let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
               self.circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow),withKey: "followTrackForever"))
            })
    }
```

Comment: all that needs to be on the touches began?

Comment: Only the scale lines substitution

Comment: what do you mean with scaleIn is terminales??

Comment: I am having difficulties cause this is new for me

Comment: thanks, the usage where do I add it?, "myAction" is an skaction that I need to create right?

Comment: no , myAction is just an example , the "Usage" is just a paragraph to explain how to use the extension.

Comment: thanks a lot Alessandro, I just dont know very well how to do this but you are a great person, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, what I try to focus is that: you make a scaleTo action , so the path of your object will change during this scale, what do you need to do is to stop the followPath and relaunch the action.

Comment: circuloFondo.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5))

Comment: So if that where my scale to action, what would i do?

Comment: cannot innove runAction with an arguyen list of tape (skAction, with key, string)

Comment: it tells me that, I would add my code to my question

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen, you must insert extension at the end of your class, just after the last brace

Comment: Thanks, what do I add in completetion?

Comment: The completion represent the exact moment or time you action was terminated, so add whatever you usually you want to do after the action execution

Comment: so the completition it could be that it stops?

Comment: No, completion simply it's like to put a chronometer to your SKAction that tell you "hey man, the action is finished just now, do whatever you want inside the braces.." dont stop nothing, simply check when action was finished

Comment: thanks men, and in the extension the SKAction is the name of the SKAction or I need to say SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5)

Comment: The extension is just like a library you must put below your class , copy and paste exactly you see starting from the word extension to the last brace, dont modify anything inside it.

Comment: func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )

Comment: The extension "extented" the power of SKNode to ensure that you can add the term "completion" to your action..

Comment: But in the SKAction I add SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5)?

Comment: dont confuse SKAction with runAction ;) , SKAction is your action, runAction is the method you permit to launch your action , so let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5) is the SKAction, the the extension library extend the powerful of "runAction" to have also the completion section

Comment: OO and my action I add it in My Game Scene? Like var scale = SKAction()

Comment: Mmh I think Im lost, Im not follow you, what do you mean?

Comment: I am a little lost too, I mean that what do I need to add in the extension? sorry for all my questions

Comment: Dont take care of extension, you must copy and paste it exactly I've wrote in my answer.It's only a library, an extension of Apple framework

Comment: let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)

Comment: I tells me use of unresolved "playerPath" I need to added outside like a var?

Comment: Try playerPath.CGPath!

Comment: class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    let playerPath = UIBezierPath()

Comment: Can i add it like that?

Comment: Right man, now I've understand. Ok, so you cannot use SKSpriteNode if you want your object give to you his path. You must use SKShapeNode, it have path as a property, if you make a circle with SKShapeNode, when you look in his property path, you have the full path (CGPath) of the circle, SKSpriteNode is used only to show sprite textures

Comment: but if I change to SKShapeNode all what a wrote with circuloFondo gives me errors

Comment: I know , you would work with shapes to have always under your eyes the path they maked, SKSpriteNode is too simple.

Comment: And how do I change the size and color of an SKShapeNode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116329/discussion-between-diego-benitez-and-alessandro-ornano).